# Using column after renaming it in Apache Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am trying to understand why Spark is behaving differently in somewhat same scenario.I renamed two columns and tried to  use both of them in some calculation but one statement is throwing en error with unable to find the renamed column .Below is the code

```
intermediateDF = intermediateDF.drop("GEO.id")
                                       .withColumnRenamed("GEO.id2", "id")
                                       .withColumnRenamed("GEO.display-label", "label")
                                       .withColumn("stateid", functions.expr("int(id/1000)"))
                                       .withColumn("countyId", functions.expr("id%1000"))
                                       //.withColumn("countyState", functions.split(intermediateDF.col("label"), ","))
                                       .withColumnRenamed("rescen42010", "real2010")
                                       .drop("resbase42010")
                                       .withColumnRenamed("respop72010", "est2010")
                                       .withColumnRenamed("respop72011", "est2011")
                                       .withColumnRenamed("respop72012", "est2012")
                                       .withColumnRenamed("respop72013", "est2013")
                                       .withColumnRenamed("respop72014", "est2014")
                                       .withColumnRenamed("respop72015", "est2015")
                                       .withColumnRenamed("respop72016", "est2016")
                                       .withColumnRenamed("respop72017", "est2017")
```

The line commented out is the one that is throwing below error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "label" among (GEO.id, GEO.id2, GEO.display-label, rescen42010, resbase42010, respop72010, respop72011, respop72012, respop72013, respop72014, respop72015, respop72016, respop72017);
```

Can someone please help me out in understanding why Spark can find one renamed column(from `GEO.id2` to `id`), runs calculations on it
but fails on other (from GEO.display-label to label). I am using Apache Spark 3 with Java.Thanks

Comment: Since you have specified the df of the column, it is not yet renamed. `//.withColumn("countyState", functions.split(col("label"), ","))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this syntax:

```
 .withColumn("countyState", functions.split(col("label"), ","))
```

It should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check below code.

```
  intermediateDF.select( \
      col("GEO.id2").alias("id"), \
      functions.expr("int(id/1000)").alias("stateid"), \
      functions.expr("id%1000").alias("countyId"), \
      split(col("GEO.display-label"),",").alias("countyState"), \
      col("rescen42010").as("real2010"), \
      col("respop72010").alias("est2010"), \
      col("respop72011").alias("est2011"), \
      col("respop72012").alias("est2012"), \
      col("respop72013").alias("est2013"), \
      col("respop72014").alias("est2014"), \
      col("respop72015").alias("est2015"), \
      col("respop72016").alias("est2016"), \
      col("respop72017").alias("est2017"))
```

Comment: Is it in python ?

Comment: Yes, its in python